# Extract URLs from String (Ruby) (Regex and link shortened)

Tags: ruby, regex, uri

I heard that `URI::extract()` only returns links with a `:`, however since I am grabbing a tweet, and it does not contain a `:`, I believe I would have to use a regular expression. I need to check for a "swoo.sh/whatever" link, and store it to a variable. However, how could I look for the first (which it returns automatically apparently), "swoo.sh/whatever" link, in regards to that I have to maintain everything after the `/`. For example, if the tweet says

> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum swoo.sh/12xfsW lorem ipsum

How would I grab the swoo.sh link, and all the different things that come directly after the `/`?

Comment: Is swoo.sh fixed?

Comment: I would assume such links are clickable on twitter, which means the original HTML would have the actual URI in it, making this task trivial. Are you sure you can't use a different API/scraper to get the actual HTML content of the tweet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `match`:

```
match = /(\w+\.\w+\/\w+)/.match("Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum swoo.sh/12xfsW lorem ipsum")
if match
    puts match[1]
else
    puts "no match"
end
```

### Demo

If you also need the simultaneous ability to capture full URLs, then my answer would have to be updated.  This only answers your immediate question.

Comment: Thank you. You answering my immediate question was all that was needed!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that URIs can't contain spaces and Ruby has [URI::Generic](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html) which will parse almost anything that looks URI-ish. Then we just need to filter out non-web-URIs, which I do by assuming that every web URI has to start with something like `foo.bar`

```
require 'uri'
require 'pathname'

tweet.
  split.
  map { |s| URI.parse(s) rescue nil }.
  select { |u| u && (u.hostname || Pathname(u.path).each_filename.first =~ /\w\.\w/) }
```

Example output

```
tweet = 'foo . < google.com bar swoosh.sh/blah?q=bar http://google.com/bar'
# the above returns
# [#<URI::Generic google.com>, #<URI::Generic swoosh.sh/blah?q=bar>, #<URI::HTTP http://google.com/bar>]
```

This can't really work in general because of ambiguity. "car.net" looks like a shortened link, but in context it could be "my neighbor threw a baseball through my window so i yanked the hubcabs off his car.net gain!!!", where it's clearly just a missing space.